# Clear array index

Tags: php, foreach, indexing, echo

How can i clear the array index.
Cause if i use foreach i only get [0] and [1]
Or should i chance the foreach code?

** SQL Datenbank select. **

```
$data = $rs->fetchAllAssoc();
```

** The Array i get when i use print_r***

```
<pre><?php print_r ($this->data); ?></pre>


Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [pid] => 0
                [sorting] => 0
                [text] => text
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [pid] => 0
                [sorting] => 0
                [text] => text
            )
    )
```

** The PHP code i use to get data ***

```
        <?php foreach ($this->data as $datafield): ?>
            <td>
            <?php echo $datafield; ?>
            </td>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**And on the page i get this **
Array Array

Comment: Iterate through internal arrays too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print_r($datafield), this is what you will get:

```
Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [pid] => 0
                [sorting] => 0
                [text] => text
            )

Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [pid] => 0
                [sorting] => 0
                [text] => text
            )
```

This means that you have not iterated the inside array i.e $this->data[0] and $this->data[1]

So you should have another inner foreach loop iterating through $datafield.

```
<?php foreach ($this->data as $datafield): ?>
         <?php foreach($datafield as $key => $value): ?>
            <td>
            <?php echo $value; ?>
            </td>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

That will give you:

```
1
0
0
text
2
0
0
text
```

Comment: Thx alot. :)
And is it possible to clear some items?
Like if don't need ID

Comment: Yes of course...use unset($datafield('id')); It will remove that array key value pair. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're only iterating through the outside array.

There should be another loop on the inside.

```
<?php foreach ($this->data as $outerIndex => $array): ?>
    <?php foreach($array as $innerIndex => $data): ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo $innerIndex; ?>
        </td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Oh thx thats perfect cause now i can made for every array a separate <tr>